# Why websocket session id changed?

Tags: java, websocket

I am connecting server using java websocket,when connected,I store the session to hashmap like this:

```
if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(roomPlayCount)) {
            roomPlayCount.stream().forEach(item -> {
                Integer currentOnlineCount = item.getOnlineCount();
                Integer roomSeatsCount = getRoomMaxAmount(roomTypeResponses, item.getRoomId());
                Double ratio = ((double) currentOnlineCount / roomSeatsCount) * 100;
                if (ratio.intValue() < playRatio) {
                    createWebsocketConnection(token, item.getRoomId(), userInfo);
                }

            });
        }
```

This is the save function:

```
private void createWebsocketConnection(String token, Long roomTypeId, Response<UserInfoResponse> userInfo) {
        WebsocketClientEndpoint websocketClientEndpoint = RobotClientOperation.robotNewConnect(roomTypeId, token);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(token) && websocketClientEndpoint != null) {
            Long userId = userInfo.getResult().getUserId();
            String sessionId = websocketClientEndpoint.userSession.getId();
            if (!websockSessions.containsKey(token)) {
                if (!isDulplicateUser(userId)) {
                    ClientSession clientSession = new ClientSession(userId, token, websocketClientEndpoint.userSession);
                    websockSessions.put(sessionId, clientSession);
                }
            } else {
                log.error("获取到了重复用户：" + JSON.toJSONString(userInfo));
            }
        }
    }
```

but when I recieved message from server,I can not get the session from id.

```
if (PlayRoomOperate.websockSessions.get(session.getId()) == null) {
          //log.warn("can not find record:" + session.getId());
          return;
}
```

Is the session id changed? What would this happend? It works fine yesterday.I found when I move the create operate outer the stream foreach,it works fine.When move the inner foreach,the situation happens.